# Equivalent condition for Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, page 3, asks this:

> If $x \in A$ has the property that $1 + Ax$ consists entirely of units, then $x \in \operatorname{rad}(A)$. Prove this.

How to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matsumura says that $\operatorname{rad}(A)$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals of $A$. If $x\notin \operatorname{rad}(A)$, then there is a maximal ideal $m$ such that $x\notin m$, so $m+Ax=A$. Can you deduce the result now?

Comment: This means there exists $a \in A$ and $y$ in the maximal ideal such that $y + ax = 1$, so $1-ax$ is in a maximal ideal, and therefore a nonunit?

Comment: Thank you! I was not used to thinking the ideal gen. by. $m$ and $x$ as $m +Ax$. This helps. Thank you again.